# Asymptotics of $\sum_{n\geq 1 } \frac{\sin n^2 t }{ n^2 } $

Tags: fourier-analysis, asymptotics, fourier-series

This is the Riemann function.

I would like to determine its asymptotics as $t \rightarrow 0^+  $.

First let $t=x^2 $, so that we treat the series

$$ \sum_{n\geq 1 }  \frac{\sin  n^2 x^2}{  n^2}.  $$

We use the Mellin transform. For that, we need the Mellin transform the function $\sin x^2$. By change of variables, and using the fact that the Mellin transform of the function $\sin x $ is $\Gamma(s) \sin \frac{\pi s }{2}$, we get

$$ \mathcal{M}[\sin x^2 ;s ] = \frac{1}{2}\Gamma(\frac{s}{2}) \sin\frac{\pi s }{4} , \;\;\;0 < Re(s) < 2.   $$

The Mellin transform the original series is then

$$   \frac{1}{2}\Gamma(\frac{s}{2}) \sin\frac{\pi s }{4} \zeta(s+2) , \;\;\;0 < Re(s) < 2.  $$

Now we use the inversion formula to recover the original series. It is

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i }\int_C x^{-s}   \frac{1}{2}\Gamma(\frac{s}{2}) \sin\frac{\pi s }{4} \zeta(s+2)  ds , $$

where we can take the integration contour $C$ to be the vertical line from $1-i\infty $ to $1+ i\infty $.

The common trick is then to shift the integration line to left. In this process, the poles of the integrand are rounded up one by one.

Now, the problem is that the gamma function has poles at $s = 0, -2, -4 ,-6,$ etc. The zeta function has a single pole at $s = -1$. The sine function has zeros at $s = 0 , -4 , -8,  $ etc.  The zeta function has zeros at $s = -4, -6, -8,$ etc.

After the cancellation, the rest poles are $s =  -1 ,  -2 $. We get a quadratic polynomial of $x$.

This is obviously wrong. The Riemann function is non-differentiable almost everywhere.

Could anyone show me where I made a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't check the growth of $\frac{1}{2}\Gamma(\frac{s}{2}) \sin\frac{\pi s }{4} \zeta(s+2)$ on vertical lines which is needed to shift the contour on the left and deduce an asymptotic.

You can look at  $$f_k(u)=f \ast \frac{k}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{- k^2 u^2/2}$$ where $$f(u) =  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(n^2 e^{-u})}{n^2}$$ then $$\mathcal{L}[f_k(u)](s) = \sin(\pi s/2)\Gamma(s) e^{s^2/(2k^2)} \zeta(2s+2)$$ this time everything is $L^1$ on vertical lines so that as $u \to \infty$, $$f_k(u) =\frac{1}{2i\pi} \int_{(-1/2-\epsilon)}\mathcal{L}[f_k(u)](s) e^{su}ds+  Res(\mathcal{L}[f_k(u)](s),s=-1/2)\\= \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2} e^{1 /(8k^2)} e^{-u/2}+O(e^{-(1/2+\epsilon)u})$$

Since $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,\infty)$ and bounded then $f_k \to f$ uniformly on $[a,\infty)$. Then we can check if the same holds for $f_k u^{-m} e^{ub}\to f u^{-m}e^{ub} $ for $b \le 1/2$

Comment: so you get a term proportional to $t^{1/2}$. Could you push it further? In your approach, you have even only one pole. Initially, I have two poles, which means I can get a $t$ term, although I am not sure whether the manipulation is legitimate.

Comment: But the Laplace transform of $f$ is not $\sin(\pi s) \Gamma(s) \zeta(2 s + 2)$ and the Laplace transform of $k/\sqrt {2 \pi} \, e^{-k^2 u^2/2}$ is not $e^{-s^2/(2 k^2)}$.

Comment: @Beamer There is a typo, the two-sided Laplace transforms of $f$ and $k/\sqrt {2 \pi} e^{-k^2 u^2/2}$ are $\sin(\pi s/2) \Gamma(s) \zeta(2 s + 2)$ and $e^{s^2/(2 k^2)}$ ($e^{-s^2}$ isn't a very good regularizer on a vertical line :)), thus the residues at $s = -1/2$ and $s = -1$ give $\sqrt { \pi t/2} - t/2$. There are no other poles, the remainder decays faster than a power of $t$.

Comment: Sure it is a two-sided Laplace transform sorry if it wasn't clear. $\mathcal{L}[f_k(u)](s)$ doesn't decay to $0$ as $\Re(s) \to -\infty$ (due to the sign of $s^2$ in the Laplace transform that I corrected) so we can't apply the residue theorem to obtain an explicit formula for $f_k$ as a sum over the poles.

Comment: I claim $\mathcal L[f]$ is still off ($\mathcal M[\sin t] = \sin(\pi s/2) \Gamma(s)$), which is why $-\Gamma(-1/2)/2 = \sqrt \pi$ is not the correct coefficient at $\sqrt t$. I'm not saying the integral is equal to the sum over the residues, but we can move the vertical line still further to the left and prove that the integral is $O(|t^p|)$ for any $p$.

Comment: right I was really tired, so $\frac{1-e^{-s/k}}{s}(F(s)- \frac{\sqrt{\pi s/2}}{s+1/2})$ is $L^1$ on $\Re(s) \ge -1/2$ which means we can take convolution with $k 1_{u \in [0,1/k]}$ instead of $ke^{-k^2 u^2/2}$

Comment: @Beamer Except the $O(|t^p|)$ part is incorrect, sorry. If the regularizer is $\exp(s^2/(2 k^2))$, the implicit constant in $O(e^{(-1/2 + \epsilon) u})$ can be made independent of $u$ but not of $k$. We cannot just pass to the limit in $k$. Apparently the $\sqrt {\pi t/2} - t/2 + O(t^{3/2})$ estimate is still true, but it requires a more careful proof, because $O(t^{3/2})$ cannot be improved.

Answer (score 1):

Let $F(z)=\sum_{n \geq 1}{\frac{e^{in^2\pi z}}{n^2}}$, bounded holomorphic on the upper plane $\mathbb{H}=\Im(z)>0$ and with a bounded continuos extension to the boundary (the reals), $R(x)=\Sigma{\frac{\sin{n^2\pi x}}{n^2}}$ its imaginary part on the reals being the function above up to a $t \to \pi x$ transformation, while customarily the cosine function (the real part of $F$) is called $C(x)$.

Using that $F$ is (almost) a primitive of the Jacobi function $\theta_0(z)=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}q^{n^2}, q=e^{i\pi z}$ as obviously $F'(z)=\frac{i\pi}{2}(\theta_0(z)-1)$, one can prove (by manipulating the functional equation of the Jacobi functions and the defintion of $F$) the following results:

1: For real $x, F(x+1)=\frac{1}{2}F(4x)-F(x)$; this follows by simple manipulations from the definition of $F$

2: For real positive $x, F(x)=F(0)+i\pi e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}\sqrt{x}-{\frac{i\pi}{2}}x+e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}x^{\frac{3}{2}}F(-\frac{1}{x})-\frac{3}{2}e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}\int_{0}^{x}\sqrt{t}F(-\frac{1}{t})dt$

3: In particular since $F$ bounded,we get for $x>0, x \to 0, F(x)=F(0)+i\pi e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}\sqrt{x}-{\frac{i\pi}{2}}x+O(x^{\frac{3}{2}})$

which gives the precise asymptotics at zero by taking the imaginary part and noting that $R$ is odd; from relation 1, we get the differentiability of $R$ at 1, with $R'(1)=-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and more generally $F'(1)=-\frac{i\pi}{2}$; also the crucial functional equation 2 above (more or less) immediately shows that $F, R, C$ are simultaneously differentiable or not at $x>0, -x, x+2, -\frac{1}{x}$, with same derivative as at $1$ so we get the famous result that $R$ is differentiable at rational numbers which are $\frac{odd}{odd}$ with derivative $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and not differentiable at rationals with denominator or numerator even in lowest form.

The proof of Hardy-Littlewood that $F,R, C$ are not differentiable at the irrationals as they are not Lipschitz of order $\frac{3}{4}$ is quite hard and depends on deeper facts about the Jacobi function and the modular group.

Comment: So, like me, you get two terms. Could you push further? It seems that the third term will not be a power of $x$. It is intriguing.

Comment: I don't think $\theta(z) = \sum_n e^{-\pi n^2 z}= z^{-1/2} \theta(1/z)$ helps for $z =iy+\epsilon$

Comment: You start from $\int_0^{x}{\theta({t+iy}})dt=x+\frac{2}{i\pi}(F(x+iy)-F(iy)), y>0$ small, for which RHS has limit $x+\frac{2}{i\pi}(F(x)-F(0))$, use the functional equation of theta above, replace $\theta(\frac{1}{z})$ by $1+\frac{2}{i\pi}F'((\frac{1}{z})$, integrate by parts getting on LHS the required terms (e.g. constant $\sqrt{x+iy}-\sqrt{iy}+$ constant ${x+iy}^{\frac{3}{2}}F(-\frac{1}{x+iy})-{iy}^{\frac{3}{2}}F(-\frac{1}{iy})$-constant required integral in $F(--\frac{1}{iy})$ and then use Lebesgue domination to let $y\to 0$ and get relation 2 which is the crux of the matter here

Comment: There a few typos above e.g. $(x+iy)^{\frac{3}{2}}, F(-\frac{1}{x+iy})$ and the comment gets too long after, but if needed I can add the computation which is fairly straightforward to the answer; the computation shows that after the first two terms in powers of $x$, the third oscillates since it has $F(-\frac{1}{x})$ as coefficient; also at most irrationals the function behaves like a $\frac{3}{4}$ power not like a square root at rationals like $0$ or those with denominator or numerator even or linear at the rationals that are ratio of odds where the function is differentiable